# What is the meaning of 'Lattices in $\mathbb R^2$ are free $\mathbb Z-$ modules'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading the chapter $12$ of Artin's Algebra,in this chapter following is written:

> 'Lattices in $\mathbb R^2$ are free $\mathbb Z-$ modules' ?

Could someone please explain me the meaning of this? I understand the definition of free modules.I don't understand the lattice meaning in this context

Comment: Is this the definition Artin gives, or a remark after giving a definition? If it isn't the definition, it might help to provide his definition of lattice in the question.

Comment: Since you know what _free modules_ are, you know that they are modules "over" some ring of scalars. Free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are just free modules whose ring of scalars is the usual ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?  Do you know what "lattice" means in this context?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Sorry,I dont know that.

Comment: @Stahl: Artin gives it as example of free module after giving the definition of free module (the one which is isomorphic to $R^n$ for some $n$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *lattice* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ generated by a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space.  For instance, if we have the basis $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, this generates the subgroup
$$\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$
A lattice is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module because if it weren't then the relation would imply a linear dependence between elements of the basis.